# How to rewrite a theorem in symbolic logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm currently working on some discrete mathematics work and I've encountered a question I'm not sure how to answer exactly. Precisely, I'm trying to translate or re-write a division algorithm into symbolic logic and my understanding of how to do that doesn't seem to be enough. The theorem in question goes as follows:

```
Write the following theorem in symbolic logic:

For any integers a,b ∈ Z, with b > 0, there exist unique integers
q and r such that
    a = qb + r  with  0 <= r < b
```

Should I make some form of truth table to better understand how this could be translated into symbolic logic? Any help is appreciated.

*Edit2:
So could it be rewritten such that

```
∀ a, b ∈ Z, where b > 0, ∃! q,r ∈ Z such that a = qb + r  with  0 <= r < b
```

or is this a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: You're not supposed to actually _do_ anything with the problem here, other than state it again with symbols instead of English words. It's not an exercise in doing anything interesting, just to make sure you understand how various standard phases in mathematical prose corresponds to symbolic formulas.

Comment: After your edit there are still English words present. It need to be all symbolic. (And you've lost the information that $q$ and $r$ are unique).

Comment: You have already met "there exists a unique", i.e. $\exists !$.

Comment: But you have to replace also "where" (with $\rightarrow$) and "with" (with $\land$) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \forall (a, b)\in\mathbb{Z},\exists!(q, r)\in\mathbb{Z}\ :\left((b\gt 0)\to\left(0\leq r\lt b \land a=qb+r\right)\right)$$